# Trying to develop a program to identify numbers that are smallest and greatest

Tags: c++, algorithm

Good evening everyone, i am attempting to write code that will determine when a number is largest and smallest.. I have asked some tutors I know for help and they have been stumped on this as well. I can not use functions or arrays or breaks. :/ Which I understand makes the process more difficult.. My professor has stated

"The only decisions staments allowed inside the loop are to determine the largest and smallest value. This means you are not allowed to use a decision to determine if the first number was entered. This is going to require you to prime your loop. We cover priming the loop in the next section but for this assignment it means get the first number before the loop begins. We will also assume that at least one number is going to be input."

I don't understand how he expects us to do something we have not learned yet, but regardless.. This is how far I have gotten on the assignment..

We have to have the user input a value to determine how many values will be input...

I keep receiving an error message after I input how many values I would like to check,

"the variable "num" is being used without being initialized.." But num is in the int!!!

Then have the software basically identify the largest and smallest... Hopefully this makes sense to someone.. If you have any questions, or if I need to clarify anything please let me know, I will do so to the best of my ability..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int number;
    int max=0;
    int num;
    int min=0;


    {   cout << "How many numbers do you want to enter" ;
        cin >> number;

        for (int i=0; num!=number; i++)
        {

            cout<<"Enter a num "; /* This is where they are supposed to place in a number, press enter, another number, press enter, until their enter presses = number*/
            cin>>num;
            if (num>max)
                max=num;
            if (num<min)
                min=num;
        }
        cout<<"largest number is: "<<max << endl;
        cout<<"smallest number is: "<<min << endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Sorry.. Been up far too long.

Comment: For what it's worth, there's an function called [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) in the standard library which determines the smallest & largest element in a range. If using that is allowed you could read a couple of numbers into e.g. a `std::vector` and then use that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
for (int i=0; num!=number; i++)
```

has undefined behavior, `num` doesn't have a value when this is first evaluated. You meant `i != number` (or, even better, `i < number`).

It would be better to use some other way of stopping, i.e. stop when a non-number is entered for instance.

**Update**: Just to clarify: there are other issues as well, such as `min` not being initialized in a way that make as many numbers as possible smaller than it. I would probably have gone for `min = INT_MAX;` or something like that. See [`<climits>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) for that constant.

Comment: PERFECT! THANK YOU! It works flawlessly now! I saw an example online where they used "input a non integer to stop" I thought that was a lot cooler... But my professor is extremely specific. Thank you again!

Comment: Does it really work flawlessly now? If you enter 1, 2 and 3 -- won't it claim that the smallest number is 0 (zero)?

Comment: Well, the other answers have specified that mistake and explained on how to correct it.

Comment: @Frerich, yes it does. I put in values of -10, -3, 0, 5, and 1000 and the program stated -10 was the smallest while 1000 was the largest

Comment: @JuliusVerne Yes, but what about my specific example: if you put in 1, 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

```
int min=0;
```

you should change that to

```
int min=std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

Otherwise, the if the number you entered is greater than 0, it will not be assigned to `min`.

> the variable "num" is being used without being initialized..

Give `num` a value, you have not given it a value before your loop starts. But that loop concept itself is wrong, try this.

```
for (int i=0; i < number; i++)
```

Comment: What is so special about 10000? What if I enter a number greater than 10000?

Comment: @Happy, I have commented on that line `// or some other huge number`, it clearly means a very large value.

Comment: If so, use `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`, not some arbitrary magic number.

Comment: okay, I'll change it. ( I haven't learned c++11, I've only learned much older versions, so I don't know about this and other functions like this ). Thanks for notifying me....

Comment: The thing about it is, we have not been introduced to the concept of numeric limits :/ If I used it, I get an automatic 70% markdown for the assignment..

Answer (score 0):

There is two problem in your code, first your min must be a great number like maximum integer, and the second is your for loop should loop on `i`. I commented lines that you need to change :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int number;
    int max=0;
    int num;
    int min=std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); // change min to maximum integer possible in c++


    {
        cout << "How many numbers do you want to enter" ;
        cin >> number;

        //for (int i=0; num !=number; i++) change this line
        for (int i=0; i<number; i++)   //to this line
        {

            cout<<"Enter a num "; /* This is where they are supposed to place in a number, press enter, another number, press enter, until their enter presses = number*/
            cin>>num;
            if (num>max)
                max=num;
            if (num<min)
                min=num;
        }
        cout<<"largest number is: "<<max << endl;
        cout<<"smallest number is: "<<min << endl;

    }
}
```